# Discrete Math: Induction and Recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the terms of the sequence that satisfy $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 2$ and $a_1 = 4$ are given by the formula $a_n =3^n + 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.

I know this problem has to do with induction. In this case I think $n = n+1$ so I would have $3^n+1$ but i'm not sure what to do with the rest of the problem. Can someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is $$a_n=3a_{n-1}-2\iff a_n-1=3(a_{n-1}-1)$$

Writing $b_n=a_n-1,$ we get $b_n=3b_{n-1}$ which implies $b_n=3^mb_{n-m}$

Now, $\displaystyle b_1=a_1-1=3,$ and setting $\displaystyle m=n-1\implies b_n=3^{n-1}b_1=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

Induction is the principle that then:

$$P(k) \quad \text{ and } \quad (\forall z) \,P(z) \implies P(z+1) \tag{1}$$

then 
$$(\forall x \ge k)\, P(x) \tag{2}$$

($k, z, x$ are integers).  You are trying to prove

$$(\forall n \ge 1)\, a_n = 3^n + 1 \tag{3}$$

First question to ask: if we are to use induction, then what are $P()$ and $k$?  You find this by comparing (2) and (3).  Comparing them you see we must choose  $k=1$ and $P(x) = \left(3^x + 1 = a_x\right)$ (note that $P()$ is a function that inputs an integer and outputs true or false).

So next thing to do is see if we can establish (1) under our choices of $P()$ and $k$:

$$P(1) \quad \text{ and } \quad (\forall z) \,\left(3^z + 1 = a_z\right) \implies \left(3^{z+1} + 1 = a_{z+1}\right) \tag{4}$$

The first half, $P(1)$, is called the base case:

$$P(1) \equiv \left(3^1 + 1 = a_1\right) \equiv (4 = a_1) \equiv \text{true}\tag{base case}$$

The second half is called the inductive case.  Under the inductive assumption $P(z)$ which is $a_n = 3^z + 1$ we must establish $P(z+1)$:

$$P(z + 1) \equiv \left(3^{z+1} + 1 = a_{n+1}\right) \equiv \left(3^{z+1} + 1 = 3a_n - 2\right) \equiv \left(3^{z+1} + 1 = 3\left(3^z + 1\right) - 2\right) \equiv \text{true}$$

So both parts of (1) are established and the inductive principle is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

$a_2 = 3a_1 - 2 = 3\cdot 4 - 2 = 10$. I've solved a very similar question that was posted here yesterday that required the generating function approach. But the characteristic equation trick seems to work well for this question also. So $x^2 - 3x = 0 \to x(x-3) = 0 \to x = 0, 3$. So the general solution would be: $a_n = p\cdot 0^n + q\cdot 3^n + r = q\cdot 3^n + r$. Using the initial conditions we obtain:
$4 = a_1 = 3q + r$, and $10 = a_2 = 9q + r \to 4 - 3q = 10 - 9q \to 6q = 6 \to q = 1$, and $4 = 3\cdot 1 + r \to r = 1$. Thus: $a_n = 1\cdot 3^n + 1 = 3^n + 1 ,\forall n \geq 1$.